# How can I check what version of twilio.js is latest?

Tags: twilio

https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/twilio-js

For example I am including http://static.twilio.com/libs/twiliojs/1.2/twilio.js file. Are there any API method or place where I can determine that version 1.2 is the latest?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio devangelist here.

The newest versions are announced through our [blog](https://blog.twilio.com), we don't have an API for discovering the latest version. The latest version is always referenced to in our [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/twilio-js) on twilio.js too.